# Sync two folders and on success copy one file from a location to the other

Tags: bash, shell-script, rsync, history-expansion

I am using rsync command to sync two folder and on success of rysnc I want to copy a file success and while copying append source folder name parameter like Success_FolderName.I am using $(basename !:3) to get the third parameter i.e Folder Name.

`bash /Sync.sh 10_03_2016`

```
#! /bin/bash

set -o history
set -o histexpand
/usr/bin/rsync -avh -r /Source/$1 /Destination/
rsyncStatus=$?
folderParam=$(basename !:3)
if($rsyncStatus==0)
then
   cp /Status/Sucesss   /Result/Success_$folderParam
else
    cp /Status/Failure   /Result/Failure_$folderParam
if
```

Output

Error

```
/Sync.sh: line 7: :3: bad word specifier
```

And File gets copied with 'Success_'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you're making this so complex. Why use the (rather finicky) `!:N` history expansion feature when you already have everything you need passed as an argument? For example:

```
#! /bin/bash

source="/Source/$1"
destination="Destination/"
folderParam="$(basename "$source")"
/usr/bin/rsync -avh -r "$source" "$destination"
rsyncStatus=$?
if($rsyncStatus==0)
then
   cp /Status/Sucesss   /Result/Success_"$folderParam"
else
    cp /Status/Failure   /Result/Failure_"$folderParam"
if
```

Or, even simpler:

```
#! /bin/bash

source="/Source/$1"
destination="Destination/"
folderParam="$(basename "$source")"
if /usr/bin/rsync -avh -r "$source" "$destination"; then
   cp /Status/Sucesss   /Result/Success_"$folderParam"
else
    cp /Status/Failure   /Result/Failure_"$folderParam"
if
```

Or even:

```
#! /bin/bash

source="/Source/$1"
destination="Destination/"
folderParam="$(basename "$source")"
touch "/Result/Failure_$folderParam"
/usr/bin/rsync -avh -r "$source" "$destination" && 
    mv /Result/Failure_"$folderParam" /Result/Success_"$folderParam"
```

Answer (score 3):

Terdon's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315885/86440) is better, but if you really want to use the history operators you can specify which command you want to refer to:

```
!rsync:3
```

will be replaced with the third parameter to the last `rsync` invocation. So in your case,

```
folderParam=$(basename !rsync:3)
```